# Regular expression help - ignoring parenthesis, ands, ors and whitespace again

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Consider the following english phrase

```
FRIEND AND COLLEAGUE AND (FRIEND OR COLLEAGUE AND (COLLEAGUE AND FRIEND AND FRIEND))
```

I want to be able to programmatically change arbitrary phrases, such as above, to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM RelationTable R1 JOIN RelationTable R2 ON R2.RelationName etc etc WHERE 
R2.RelationName = FRIEND AND R2.RelationName = Colleague AND (R3.RelationName = FRIENd, 
etc. etc.
```

My question is. How do I take the initial string, strip it of the following words and symbols : AND, OR, (, ), 
Then change each word, and create a new string.

I can do most of it, but my main problem is that if I do a string.split and only get the words I care for, I can't really replace them in the original string because I lack their original index. Let me explain in a smaller example:

```
string input = "A AND (B AND C)"
Split the string for space, parenthesies, etc, gives: A,B,C
input.Replace("A", "MyRandomPhrase")
```

But there is an A in AND.
So I moved into trying to create a regular expression that matches exact words, post split, and replaces. It started to look like this:

```
"(\(|\s|\))*" + itemOfInterest + "(\(|\s|\))+"
```

Am I on the right track or am I overcomplicating things..Thanks !

Comment: You'd be better implementing a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) algorithm in this case, it's a lot better suited for language parsing.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure - I have a feeling that you'd be better off with some kind of grammar parser - however, the regex '\b' will help you, as it works as a word-boundry marker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Regex.Replace`, with `\b` word boundary regex

```
string input = "A AND B AND (A OR B AND (B AND A AND A))";
string pattern = "\\bA\\b";
string replacement = "MyRandomPhrase";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string text = "A AND (B AND C)";

        List<object> result = ParseBlock(text);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<object> ParseBlock(string text)
    {
        List<object> result = new List<object>();

        int bracketsCount = 0;
        int lastIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = text[i];

            if (c == '(')
                bracketsCount++;
            else if (c == ')')
                bracketsCount--;

            if (bracketsCount == 0)
                if (c == ' ' || i == text.Length - 1)
                {
                    string substring = text.Substring(lastIndex, i + 1 - lastIndex).Trim();

                    object itm = substring;

                    if (substring[0] == '(')
                        itm = ParseBlock(substring.Substring(1, substring.Length - 2));

                    result.Add(itm);

                    lastIndex = i;
                }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's [not an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) but merely an uncommented code block.